# Is Sebastian trying to protect Annette's reputation?

Tags: plot-explanation, cruel-intentions

In the film *Cruel Intentions* toward the end of the movie, Kathryn threatens to call the new headmaster of the school (Annette's father) if Sebastian doesn't break up with Annette. This would destroy her reputation as pure and virginal.

Is this the real reason he breaks up with her? Alternatively, did he really let Kathryn's words, about how his love for Annette would ruin his own twisted reputation, destroy the relationship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the end despite the earlier machinations that take place, he developed real feelings for her and had started to feel protective of her.